# Splitting row values and count unique's from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, data-wrangling

I have the following data in a column titled **Reference**:

```
ABS052
ABS052/01
ABS052/02
ADA010/00
ADD005
ADD005/01
ADD005/02
ADD005/03
ADD005/04
ADD005/05
...
WOO032
WOO032/01
WOO032/02
WOO032/03
WOO045
WOO045/01
WOO045/02
WOO045/03
WOO045/04
```

I would like to know how to split the row values to create a Dataframe  that contains the single Reference code, plus a Count value, for example:

| Reference | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ABS052 | 3 |
| ADA010 | 0 |
| ADD005 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| WOO032 | 3 |
| WOO045 | 4 |

I have the following code:
`df['Reference'] = df['Reference'].str.split('/')`

Results in:

```
['ABS052'],
['ABS052','01'],
['ABS052','02'],
['ABS052','03'],
...
```

But I'm not sure how to ditch the last two digits from the list in each row.

All I want now is to keep the string in each row `[0]` if that makes sense, then I could just retrieve a `value_count` from the `'Reference'` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the expected result listed in the question.

Let's say you want to ditch the digits and count the prefix occurrences:

```
df.Reference.str.split("/", expand=True)[0].value_counts()
```

If instead the suffix means something and you want to keep the highest value this should do

```
df.Reference.str.split("/", expand=True).fillna("00").astype({0: str, 1: int}).groupby(0).max()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use regex to replace the last two digits like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['ABS052','ABS052/01','ABS052/02','ADA010/00','ADD005','ADD005/01','ADD005/02','ADD005/03','ADD005/04','ADD005/05']})
df = df['a'].str.replace(r'\/\d+$', '').value_counts().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>>>    index   a
    0   ADD005  6
    1   ABS052  3
    2   ADA010  1
```

Comment: Include end of line '$' in your regex pattern for more convinience.

Comment: Ah yes, good suggestion. Edited. Thank you @Hamzausmanghani

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you can add `expand=True` to `split` and then use `groupby`:

```
df['Reference'].str.split("/", expand=True).fillna("--").groupby(0).count()
```

returns:

```
        1
0        
ABS052  3
ADA010  1
ADD005  6
```

for the first couple of rows of your data.

The `fillna("--")` makes sure you also count lines like `ABS052` without a "", i.e. `None` in the second column.

Comment: I think you have a typo `explode=True` in the first line :)

Comment: @Aditya K - thanks, at least the code was correct...

Answer (score 0):

Output to df with column names

```
df['Reference'] = df['Reference'].str.split('/').str[0]
df_counts = df['Reference'].value_counts().rename_axis('Reference').reset_index(name='Counts')
```

output

```
  Reference  Counts
0    ADD005  6
1    ABS052  3
2    ADA010  1
```

Explanation - The first line gives a clean series called 'Reference'. The second line gives a count of unique items and then resets the index and renames the columns.